# How to copy file from remote linux machine to JSP web directory

Tags: java, linux, jsp, servlets

I want to create a JSP webpage which contains a button on click of which I want to copy a file from remote linux machine to my local directory (in windows) where JSP pages are hosted. I have the UserID and Password of that machine and I can connect to the remote server using SSH command in putty.

I am using Eclipse Indigo and Tomcat Server.

Comment: are you looking for someone to give you the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to have a pure Java implementation of the SSH protocol and copy your file.
File transfer (`scp` command) with `JSch` can be a bit tricky, so you can add [securechannelfacade](http://code.google.com/p/securechannelfacade/) to transfer your file properly

Answer (score 0):

Could you use FTP from the remote machine?